# Asking user whether he/she wants to play again but typing yes just repeats this question again rather starting again

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

It is a number guessing game

**Explanation**

At first it asks the user to enter a number between 1 to 50
Then if the number is correct then you win else you have to try again (**The winning number is random offcourse**)You also have limited guesses

**The problem is mentioned below the code**
Here is my code:)

```
import random
winning_num = 23
guesses = 1
guesses_left = 9
game_over = False
end_game = False
number_enter = False
while not end_game:    
    while not number_enter:
        try:
            ask = int(input("ENTER A NUMBER BETWEEN 1 AND 50: "))
            print(f"TOTAL GUESSES = {guesses_left}")
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("INVALID INPUT!!")
            continue
    while not game_over: 
        if ask==winning_num:
            print(f"YOU WON BY GUESSING THE NUMBER IN {guesses} TIME(S)!!")
            print("DO YOU WANT TO PLAY AGAIN?")
            while True:
                ask1 = input("ENTER 'YES' OR 'NO' ONLY: ")
                ask1 = ask1.lower()
                if ask1=='yes':
                    print("YOU CHOSE TO PLAY AGAIN")
                    game_over = False
                    break
                elif ask1=="no":
                    print("THANK YOU FOR PLAYING THIS GAME")
                    game_over = True
                    end_game = True
                    break
                else:
                    print("PLEASE WRITE 'YES' OR 'NO' ONLY ")
                    continue
            

        elif ask>winning_num:
            print("TOO HIGH!!")
            guesses+=1
            guesses_left-=1
            while True:
                try:
                    ask = int(input("TRY AGAIN: "))
                    print(f"GUESSES LEFT = {guesses_left}")
                    break
                except ValueError:
                    print("INVALID INPUT!!")
                    continue
            if guesses_left==1:
                print("ONLY ONE GUESS LEFT!!")
                continue
            elif guesses_left==0:
                print("YOU LOSE!!")
                break
        elif ask<winning_num:
             print("TOO LOW!!")
             guesses+=1
             guesses_left-=1
             while True:
                 try:
                     ask = int(input("TRY AGAIN: "))
                     print(f"GUESSES LEFT = {guesses_left}")
                     break
                 except ValueError:
                     print("INVALID INPUT!!")
                     continue
             if guesses_left==1:
                 print("ONLY ONE GUESS LEFT!!")
                 continue
             elif guesses_left==0:
                 print("YOU LOSE!!")
                 break
```

> The problem is when the game ends
> It asks whether we want to play again
> But if we type **"Yes"** it again asks the same "Do you want to play again"
> However typing **"No"** works fine and the program ends

Comment: Because as it is, the while not game_over is called over and over because not game_over is True.

Answer (score 1):

you have to set game_over = False in case ask1 = yes so that it can come out of the parent while loop and proceed. Also, you'll have to reset number of guesses etc so that it starts as a new game.

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
winning_num = 23
guesses = 1
guesses_left = 9
game_over = False
end_game = False
number_enter = False
while not end_game:    
    while not number_enter:
        try:
            ask = int(input("ENTER A NUMBER BETWEEN 1 AND 50: "))
            print(f"TOTAL GUESSES = {guesses_left}")
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("INVALID INPUT!!")
            continue
    while not game_over: 
        if ask==winning_num:
            print(f"YOU WON BY GUESSING THE NUMBER IN {guesses} TIME(S)!!")
            print("DO YOU WANT TO PLAY AGAIN?")
            while True:
                ask1 = input("ENTER 'YES' OR 'NO' ONLY: ")
                ask1 = ask1.lower()
                if ask1=='yes':
                    print("YOU CHOSE TO PLAY AGAIN")
                    game_over = True
                    break
                elif ask1=="no":
                    print("THANK YOU FOR PLAYING THIS GAME")
                    game_over = True
                    end_game = True
                    break
                else:
                    print("PLEASE WRITE 'YES' OR 'NO' ONLY ")
                    continue
        

        elif ask>winning_num:
            print("TOO HIGH!!")
            guesses+=1
            guesses_left-=1
            while True:
                try:
                    ask = int(input("TRY AGAIN: "))
                    print(f"GUESSES LEFT = {guesses_left}")
                    break
                except ValueError:
                    print("INVALID INPUT!!")
                    continue
            if guesses_left==1:
                print("ONLY ONE GUESS LEFT!!")
                continue
            elif guesses_left==0:
                print("YOU LOSE!!")
                break
        elif ask<winning_num:
             print("TOO LOW!!")
             guesses+=1
             guesses_left-=1
             while True:
                 try:
                     ask = int(input("TRY AGAIN: "))
                     print(f"GUESSES LEFT = {guesses_left}")
                     break
                 except ValueError:
                     print("INVALID INPUT!!")
                     continue
             if guesses_left==1:
                 print("ONLY ONE GUESS LEFT!!")
                 continue
             elif guesses_left==0:
                 print("YOU LOSE!!")
                 break
```

Comment: you have to correct the ask1 yes and gameover to true not false

Answer (score 0):

You toggle game_over incorrectly, it should be set to `True`, not to `False` if the answer to replay is yes.

```py
while not end_game:  # End game must be false to replay
    while not number_enter:
        #... ask number
    while not game_over: # But Game_over should be True to stop asking to replay
        #... Check number good
        #... Ask to replay
        while True:
            ask1 = input("ENTER 'YES' OR 'NO' ONLY: ")
            ask1 = ask1.lower()
            if ask1=='yes':
                print("YOU CHOSE TO PLAY AGAIN")
                game_over = True  # <<<< Thats the problematic part, it must be True
                                  #      in your code it is False, So it result in
                                  #      an "infinite" loop, if yes.
                break
```